# Capitalize first letter of words in a string

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I'm having trouble figuring out how to transform a string into camel case in groovy.  Say I start out with a string that looks like "1-800 FOO.BAR".  Ultimately, I want this to turn into "1800FooDotBar".  I've been able to get 1800FOODotBar by doing the following:

```
String str = "1-800 FOO.BAR"
String tempStr = str.replaceAll(/(?i)\.com/, "DotCom")
String newStr = tempStr.replaceAll(/\\W/, "")
```

I'm just not sure how to get rid of those capital letters in the middle.  I've come across some information about a capitalize() method that should be able to help, but I'm just not familiar enough with Groovy to know how to use it.  I think I need to split the string into individual strings for each word and then capitalize the first letter of each of those strings, but then how do I build the end result back up?  I know that similar questions have been asked, but I'm just not seeing how to take that information and make complete Groovy code from it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will your strings *always* be trivially-splitable?

Comment: I believe so.  They come in from a list of names, so I think I should always just be able to split on either white space or punctuation.  Another example would be "FOO, BAR."  This should be turned into "FooBar".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very roughly:

```
String str = "1-800 FOO.BAR"
println str.replaceAll(/\./, " Dot ").split(/[^\w]/).collect { it.toLowerCase().capitalize() }.join("")
=> 1800FooDotBar
```

Comment: Why only "roughly"? Seems like exactly what he asked for

Comment: @Don Barely tested, and could probably be reduced in verbosity a bit :)